# verilog register with clock

Tags: verilog, register

Now, I've been learning Verilog but I got stuck with some easy problems.

```
always@(posedge clock)
if(reset == 1’b1) leds_r <=0;
else leds_r <= leds_r + 1;
```

I can understand `if(reset==1'b1)leds_r<=0;` 
but the matter is `else leds_r <= leds_r+1;` what is that means?

I activated that with only `always@(posedge clock) leds_r <=leds_r+1;` code
using Spartan-3A/AN Starter Kit Board then, after I pushed reset button, all the leds were cleared.

Comment: 'else' is a computer programming word for 'otherwise'.

Comment: I mean, I can't understand leds_r <=leds_r+1; I'm sorry I forgot adding passage reg [27:0]  leds_r;

Comment: It means the register `leds_r` changes from whatever value it had to one more than that. It's the usual way to express a counter in Verilog.

Comment: `<=` means non-blocking assignment. I.e. it is basically saying increment `leds_r` by 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially the meaning behind Register Transfer Level(RTL) abstraction coding. You are describing the transfer of data to registers at each clock cycle. The English translation of the code would be:

> At the rising clock edge, if `reset` is true the register `leds_r` gets
>   the value `0`, otherwise, the register `leds_r` gets the current value of
>   the expression `leds_r + 1`